# toggle between disabled and enabled on jQueryUI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uhyyh9sL/1/)

I have a jQueryUI range slider that is disabled by default.

```
$( ".sliderrange" ).slider({
  range: true,
  disabled: true,
  min: 100,
  max: 200,
  values: [ 75, 300 ],    
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $('input').val( ui.values[ 0 ].toFixed(2) + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ].toFixed(2) +" mm");
  }
});
```

Is there any way to toggle the slider between disabled and enabled with a checkbox just like what it does on the input box?

```
$('.check').change(function(){
  var slide = $('.sliderrange'),
      input = $('.mm');
      input.prop('disabled', function (_, val) { return ! val; });  // working for the input box
      slide.slider("enable", this.disable); // not working for the slider.
});
```

HTML

```
 Enable<input type='checkbox' class='check'>
<div class="sliderrange"></div>
<input class='mm' type='text'  disabled>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add this which uses the slider's [disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-disable) method:

```
if(!$(this).is(":checked"))$( ".sliderrange" ).slider( "disable" );
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uhyyh9sL/5/)**